# Why browser downloads index.php after wordpress installation on nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-config

here is my nginx config

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


        root /var/www/domain_name/html;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name domain_name;

        location / {
        #        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain_name;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

I tried rebooting the server and clearing browser cache as was mentioned in other answers but it didnt work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your server what to do with a PHP file. Right now, your server doesn't know, so it sends it to the browser to be downloaded. You need to add code like this (assuming you're on PHP7) to tell your server to process a PHP file.

```
  location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Another tutorial [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem from your server not load `JS` and `CSS` file

So you need to check the file permission in linux of file

**File Permissions**

Incorrect file permissions are another cause of the "403 Forbidden" error. The standard setting of 755 for directories and 644 for files is recommended for use with NGINX. The NGINX user also needs to be the owner of the files.

Identify the NGINX User
To begin, you will need to determine what user NGINX is running as. To do this, use the command:

```
ps -ef | grep nginxmixed
```

Check the first column, for any of the NGINX worker processes:

In this example, the NGINX worker process is running as the user nginx.

Set File Ownership
Go to the directory above the website's document root. For example, if your website's document root is /usr/share/nginx/example.com go to /usr/share/nginx with the command:

```
cd /usr/share/nginxmixed
```

Change the ownership of all the files from this point down to the nginx user with the command:

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx *mixed
```

Set Permissions
Set the permissions of each directory at this location to 755 with the command:

```
sudo chmod 755 [directory name]mixed
```

For example, to set the permissions of the example.com directory, the command is:

```
sudo chmod 755 example.commixed
```

Then go to the web document root directory:

```
cd example.commixed
```

Change the permissions of all the files in this directory with the command:

```
sudo chmod 644 *
```